# sql query to fetch data with a time interval

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I got a data table with a field of type date time and i got data like 3-5 entries for every minute ie,

```
23/08/2012 18:05:01,
23/08/2012 18:05:15,
23/08/2012 18:05:26,
23/08/2012 18:05:44,
23/08/2012 18:05:59
```

now i need to get data one record for every 5th minute

can any one please help me how can i do this one

Thanks

Comment: any particular record in that every-5 grouping? first? last? random?

Comment: Three things:  (1)  What have you tried so far?  (2) For each minute that's divisible by 5, select one record?  (3) Since there will be more than one record per minute, how do you know which one to select?

Comment: not every one in 5 i need to get the records with a user defined time interval say 5 min like that

Comment: I tried taking every 10th ,15th records but the time is not matching, then i noticed i need to fetch the records based on that time field

Comment: @Srikanth do you want the minutes to be in regular intervals of 5, 10, 15, etc? starting at 0?

Comment: yes that what i am looking for @bluefeet

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not sure if I fully understand your requirements, but the following will return one record for any value where the minute is a multiple of 5:

```
select *
from
(
    select *, 
       datepart(minute, yourDate) mn, 
       row_number() over(partition by datepart(minute, yourDate) order by yourDate) rn
    from yourTable
) x
where (mn % 5) = 0
    and rn = 1
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/114a2/1)

Answer (score 0):

Given a table that looks something like this:

```
create table some_event_log_table
(
  id             int      not null identity(1,1) primary key clustered ,
  dateTimeLogged datetime not null ,
  ... some more columns here --
)
```

Then a query like the following (SqlFiddle at http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/5ad56/1/0) should do the trick:

```
select dateLogged    = convert(date,dateTimeLogged),
       periodID      = datediff(minute,
                         convert(date,dateTimeLogged) ,
                         dateTimeLogged
                         ) / 5   ,
       period_start  = convert(time,
                         dateadd(minute,
                           datediff(minute,
                             convert(date,dateTimeLogged),
                             dateTimeLogged
                             ) ,
                           convert(datetime,convert(date,dateTimeLogged))
                           )
                         ) ,
       events_logged = count(*)
from some_event_log_table
group by convert(date,dateTimeLogged),
         datediff(minute,
           convert(date,dateTimeLogged) ,
           dateTimeLogged
           ) / 5   ,
         convert(time,
           dateadd(minute,
             datediff(minute,
               convert(date,dateTimeLogged),
               dateTimeLogged
               ) ,
             convert(datetime,convert(date,dateTimeLogged))
             )
           )
```

What we are 9doing here is the following.

- First, we divide the day up into periods of 5 minutes each. There are 288 such 5 minute periods every day.
- Then, for each row in the table, we

  - Compute the column `dateLogged`, the reporting date (*sans* time) for the row.
  - Compute the column `periodID`, a value from 0-287, indicating which of the 288 5-minute periods per day the row falls into.
  - Compute the column `periodStart`, the start time of the period the row falls into.
- Finally, we

  - Summarize with `group by`, creating 1 group for each period within a day, grouping on the 3 values we just computed for each row.
  - Order the result set with `order by` on the columns `dateLogged` and `periodID`.

That's about all there is to it. Really quite simple, once you break it down.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with that is you have 2 periodid 218 rows, how about an average of period 218?

Comment: I know you can't comment yet, but this should be a comment :-)